# Why are foreign key names created with an underscore in EF

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have read and understood the convention. I have followed the convention and in most cases the sql column name for foreign key is 'ForeignKeyEntityId' in the database. Unfortunately this is not always consistent and I get ForeignKeyEntity_Id as the sql column name.

```
public class Step : BaseModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<StepRecord> _stepRecords;


    public Step()
    {
        _stepRecords = new ObservableCollection<StepRecord>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; } 

    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }


    public int? PassStatusTypeId;
    public  virtual PassStatusType PassStatusType


    public int? SaveStatusTypeId;
    public  virtual SaveStatusType SaveStatusType

    public int? StepTypeId;
    public virtual StepType StepType { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<StepRecord> StepRecords { get; set; } 
}
```

All of the references in this class are named with ForeignKeyEntity_Id pattern. This is not what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably Entity Framework does not map public fields at all, only public properties. As a result the fields `PassStatusTypeId`, `SaveStatusTypeId` and `StepTypeId` are not recognized as foreign keys and EF creates its own foreign key columns that have an underscore in their names by convention. You should use properties instead:

```
public int? PassStatusTypeId { get; set; }
public virtual PassStatusType PassStatusType { get; set; }

public int? SaveStatusTypeId { get; set; }
public  virtual SaveStatusType SaveStatusType { get; set; }

public int? StepTypeId { get; set; }
public virtual StepType StepType { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried that as well(removing public fields) with the same result. It could be a just an EF anomaly, but it might also mean I will be unable to use .Include to load the reference - that is the result as I have tested it. Also, I have not been able to explicitly set the key and have it save to the database as in PassStatusTypeId=4

Comment: @MikeAgee: When you define `PassStatusTypeId` *as a property* do you have *both* a `PassStatusTypeId` and a `PassStatusType_Id` column in the database? Or only one of those two?

Comment: Only PassStatusType_Id. I really am beginning to think that EF has lost its way when decomposing this class. I created another foreign key relationship to a do nothing little class Mike. With a property named MikeId it too creates in the database a column named Mike_Id.

Comment: One more thing - I just placed a [ForeignKey("PassStatusTypeId")]
        public  virtual PassStatusType PassStatusType in the class and now receive The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'PassStatusType' on type 'EmissionTestingModels.Models.Step' is not valid. The foreign key name 'PassStatusTypeId' was not found on the dependent type 'EmissionTestingModels.Models.Step'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names. This does seem to support my theory that EF is confused here.

Comment: @MikeAgee: And your `PassStatusTypeId` is **REALLY** a property (`public int? PassStatusTypeId { get; set; }`) and not only a field (`public int? PassStatusTypeId;`) like in your question???

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to give a specific name to your foreign keys you can use the ForeignKey attribute like this:

```
[ForeignKey("MyChildEntity")]
public int? ChildEntityId {get;set;}
public ChildEntity MyChildEntity {get;set;}
```

In this case, your database will use the ChildEntityId name instead of the default naming convention.

In your case it would be something like:

```
[ForeignKey("PassStatusType")]
public int? PassStatusTypeId {get;set;}
public  virtual PassStatusType PassStatusType {get;set;}
```